# Texmaker Toolbar More buttons

Tags: fontsize, texmaker

I've just updated Texmaker to 4.0.2. I've enabled the "file", "edit" and "tools" toolbars. But there is no buttons for changing font size etc. (E.g. in link below where is says "part", "label" and "tiny")

[image]

In earlier versions I have installed of Texmaker these buttons have always been there from the start, but now I can't seem to find them. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Check version 4.0.2 and Is this font size buttons what you need ?](http://i.imgur.com/qkrmfsP.png)

Comment: @texenthusiast Would you like to make that an answer?

Answer (score 5):

We can change the text font size by going to menu "Options" > "Configure TexMaker"

Then the window "Configure TexMaker" appears.  Inside that window, you click the third tab "Editor" and you can change the font size.

[image]

Comment: Texmaker development looks frozen, last version 4.5 dated Oct 29 2015 doesn't handle HD screens and all icons are tiny-tiny, hard to work with.

Answer (score 4):

Converting my comment to answer as suggested by [Torbjørn T](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbjorn-t) in comment:

In TeXmaker [Version 4.0.2](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html) buttons to change `font size` are available as shown in screenshot below.

[image]