# Font size in the TEX typing box

Tags: fonts, texmaker, letters

I use the Texmaker compiler. I would like to know how do I increase the letter in the TEX typing box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Texmaker Toolbar More buttons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122362/texmaker-toolbar-more-buttons) Especially the second answer may be useful, which is about the font size of the editor (the first answer is how to set font size of text in the document).

Comment: Please change "TEX" in the question header and text to "TeX".  It may seem trivial, but it's a trademark issue, and it's polite to observe such niceties.